# Symmetry of two-sided ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, ideals

I was thinking about two-sided ideals and have some intuition-guided, soft questions regarding them.  Since I don't have anyone to talk to about such subject matter,  I thought I'd ask.

Let $a$ be an element of $A$, a two-sided ideal of the ring $R$.
If $R$ is not commutative, then the possibility arises where $ra \neq ar$, $r$ being an element of $R$ (as in the case of a matrix ring over a ring $R$ and its two-sided, non-commutative ideal $M_n(A)$).

Then $A$ contains the same elements in both its left and right, but the structure relating those elements must differ.

Is there a classification of two-sided ideals that are symmetrical in right and left?  If a two-sided ideal has asymmetry, are there conditions that cause it to be simple (like the matrix ring with elements from a field)?

Comment: What do these sentences mean? 1) *Then A contains the same elements in both its left and right* 2)  *the structure relating those elements must differ.* 3) *two-sided ideals that are symmetrical in right and left?*  It's really hard to understand what you're asking.  What kind of classification are you imagining? Do you really just mean some alternative description?

Comment: If a ring is commutative then the notions of left, right, and two-sided ideals all coincide. The commutativity seems to  setting is thus perhaps one which satisfies your notion of being symmetric. If $R$ is noncommutative and $A$ is a *two-sided* ideal, then for any $a\in A, r \in R$, *both* $ra$ and $ar$ lie in $A$, but they need not be equal, nor need either be equal to $r$, so I don't know what you mean when you say $A$ contains the same element in both its left and right.